# setting an HTTP header variable on a wordpress media asset

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want my wordpress asset wp-content/uploads/2016/11/stellar.toml to return an extra HTTP header.  I tried adding the following to my functions.php, but the header variable is not working.  Can anyone see if I'm missing something?

```
add_action('template_redirect','yoursite_template_redirect');

function yoursite_template_redirect() {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='wp-content/uploads/2016/11/stellar.toml') 
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        echo 'data';
        exit();
    }
}
```